# I get "can't reach this page" message when I type my website URL

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

My website crkey.org has stopped working and I cannot access WordPress backend. I bought this google domain a month ago and created my website on 2021-04-19 using the WordPress app from google cloud marketplace. I have changed the IP address in WordPress settings into HTTPS instead of HTTP. Do you have a way to change it again as I cannot access my WordPress backend?

1. I get this message when I try to put my website URL "can't reach this page".
2. I have SSL certificate but it showed  "not secure" on my website before stopping working.
3. WordPress load-balancer shows that it's unhealthy

Answer (score 0):

First find out what the WP prerequisites for enabling SSL on the particular host are, you know, stuff like additional plugins you have to install and/or settings you have to make in wp-config.php.
If it is some setting in wp-config.php you have to add/change then it might be quite simple and straight forward to bring your site back.

If you have command line access on the host where you are hosting your site, you can install WP-CLI ( https://wp-cli.org/ ) and gain access to your site's backend that way.
This should make it quite easy to e.g. install a missing plugin or roll back the settings you made that caused the problem in the first place.

If you don't have commad line access, you could try to access WP's database directly and roll back the changes manually, one by one, until you gain access again.

If none of the ways work for you, you can always hope for another answer ;)